# ng-bind not showing scope variables {{ }}

Tags: angularjs

test.html (my template):

```
<span data-ng-bind="emailSent.info"></span>
```

js:

```
$scope.resetPasswordEmail = "my@email.here";
// info is taken from a database with different languages
$scope.emailSent = { 
    info: getInfoFromDatabase() // returns: 'Confirmation email sent to {{resetPasswordEmail}}, check your email.'
};
angular.element(document.body).append($compile($templateCache.get('test.html'))($scope));
```

However this results in the following in the span on the page:

```
Confirmation email sent to {{resetPasswordEmail}}, check your email.
```

I'm attempting to do "nested" scope variables. Do I have to re-compile the compiled template again. **Or is there a proper angularjs way of achieving this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated question, I see why you're doing this.

The key to do it is to use [$interpolate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate):

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $interpolate, $compile){
  $scope.resetPasswordEmail = "my@email.here";
  $scope.emailSent = {
    info: $interpolate(getInfoFromDatabase())($scope)
  };
  
  function getInfoFromDatabase(){
    return 'Confirmation email sent to {{resetPasswordEmail}}, check your email.'
  }
  angular.element(document.body).append($compile('<span data-ng-bind="emailSent.info"></span>')($scope));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew AngularJS somehow could achieve this. +1 for the example.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I didn't understand what you were doing at first. :)